# HTML5 Date field format preference

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML5 Date input on my Webapp which is mostly used on tablets.

On Desktop when I check the format in which I enter, It is dd/mm/yyyy, I can just go ahead and enter it in same format.

On tablet when I touch the field It opens big Popup with sliders for Date, Month & Year, After I select everything. It goes back to normal view but now date format mentioned there is in format of mm/dd/yyyy

Is there any way to keep same format for both desktop and tablet and preferably Keep dd/mm/yyyy for both.

```
<input type="date" name="bday">
```

or you can consider any datepicker

Live example you may get here
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: @KristofferSall-Storgaard link above is three years old. Was wondering if there are any more options provided currently.